# XMLHttpRequest HTTP Headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a little script to rehost pictures on the web on imgur.

This is called Image Sideloading and you only need to point the browser to http://api.imgur.com/2/upload?url= + Picture's Url

It doesn't return any XML or JSON response so I can't parse it to get the img URL.

But I think I found a way to do this but can't get it to work properly. Here's the code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        str = $("input").val().toString();
        link = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload?url=" + str;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", link);
        xhr.send();
        var headers = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase;
        alert(headers);

    });

});
```

And looking at Google Chrome's console these are the results generated after the script runs.

I am not allowed to post images yet so here's a link to the results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAKC2.png

I need to somehow access that 4th response header because even though this method doesn't return any parsable XML or JSON response that link is the uploaded img's URL which is all I need.

So is there a way to access that info? Why is it cancelled?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the API must return something, else it is useless.

Actually, http://api.imgur.com/examples advises you to do something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", link);
xhr.onload = function() {
    var url = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
    alert(url);
}
xhr.send();
```

**Edit.** OK, I got it. Normally, the above code should work, but I think imgur is facing a problem. I will report the bug.

While the bug is still there, here is a dirty solution to serve your needs:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", link);
xhr.onload = function() {
    html = xhr.responseText;
    alert(html.substr(html.indexOf('http://i.imgur.com/') + 19, 5));
}
xhr.send();
```

You code wasn't working because you weren't waiting for the answer. You have to catch it through a callback function.

**Edit.** The above code only works locally. As you're using jQuery, let me introduce the shortcut `$.post`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $.post('http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json', {
            key: 'ec575de603b936e54c2b4a9f232d537e',
            image: $("input").val().toString()
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data.upload.image.hash);
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Le_Sphinx/rEfdS/

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help but it's still not working. What I mean by "returns nothing" is that the example uses a link that you're only allowed to use if you have an API key. The method I am talking about is probably supposed to be used to create a new tab. If you try that request just by putting the link in the browser it'll load a few seconds and automatically redirect you to the img link. I should try to load the page in a hidden frame probably? That would allow me to actually have the page open and get all the info I need from there. Not really efficient though.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. The code I posted only works locally, on jsFiddle I'm having an error `Please use POST request`. But why don't you want to use an API key? I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Just added a jsFiddle so you can try.

Comment: So I see it works just fine using an API key.. Thank you! I was just curious to see if it could be done without having to use one since in the generated responses there was the img link so I thought there had to be a way to. Apparently not. Thank you for your help! By the way what do you exactly mean by "only works locally"? I have both html and js "locally" on my desktop if that's what you mean and it still didn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: Were you using a PHP server? I weren't, this might explain why it worked for me but not for you. You're welcome!

Comment: Neither I was. I just had the files in a folder on desktop and nothing worked. Now I used the code with the API key and it worked just fine. I'm still curious though why the second block of code you posted worked for you but not for me. There has to be something basic I'm missing here.